# Hyper-V Redundancy without Domain

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, failover

We currently run a Hyper-V server on a non-domain W2008 server, and are looking to build a failover solution. 
Because all the (6-10) VM guests are linuxes, and our datacenter space is 90% non windows, we have never felt the need for AD domains etc.

My initial plan is a second server (either W2008R2 or W2012 standard), running Hyper-V server.

There is no shared storage / SAN in place.

The VM's are pretty static - portals and web servers, with database located elsewhere, off the VMs, and so we could reasonably easily cope with week-old backups copies regularly from master VM to secondary VM.

Option 1 is the above setup - if VM Server goes bang, spin up the copies on secondary.

Option 2 is implement Failover Cluster, so if VM Server goes down, VM Secondary will just take over

I would really appreciate some advice on the way forwards with this - the more I read the more confused I get.

Comment: Can I just ask, if you're a non-MS shop, why Hyper-V at all? Would one of the other big names not suit you better?

Comment: Are you running the free Hyper-V server?

Comment: Yeah. Currently server running VM's is W2008 Std (not R2), so an upgrade looks likely to be needed anyway. Half an hour's downtime while we spin up the guests on the standby is not a crisis. But automagic transfer from one to the other would be nice (especially if it's 3am and I'm tucked up in bed). But I feel very vulnerable with one VM server - if the power supply goes bang, or the processor explodes, I am stuffed.

Comment: The question on why use Hyper-V is still a valid question. If you're not a Windows server shop in general, why go Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but why do you NEED that?

I mean, can you not handle the high uptime requirement on the VM level? Have 2 sets of vm's (one on each server) and then do the HA part in the software.

- Databases should support that out of the box of with some third party. SQL Server for example can do that (mirror, high availablility)
- Web machines should support that too.

Basically, assume a Hyper-V server CAN crash, and handle the failure WITHIN the VM layer, similar like you would do it if that all would not be virtual but every VM would be a physical machine.

Any HA for Hyper-V requires a domain as this is what windows clustering uses. And that still leaves issues (corrupt images). But that is not HA anyway (requires restart) and there still is the app layer level.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. Using virtualisation for redundancy at the hypervisor level is completely reasonable and is half the reason that companies go the virtual route.

Comment: Ah, yes, but then this has a "get a domain in place" requirement. Plus this is not a real solution in many scenarios - I personally go down BOTH ways. Some machines are like that, some are internally handled, mostly that which are important. But anyhow, Hyper-V HA requirements ARE laid out and they DO require shared storage and a domain. Point. Fight requirements - your problem.

Comment: @TomTom Hyper-V in WS2012 does not require shared storage for failover clustering.

Comment: @pauska Please show references, because this is BULL. Either shared storage, or replication which has a time delay and not HA but business continuity. Hyper-V does not support real time replication. I unerstand you do not know Hyper-V.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you are saying here (certainly due to my lack of knowledge on windows systems - last time I was a sysadmin for domains was NT4!). Optopn 1 would have clones on each guest on each vm server, so standby guests could not spin up as their (static) ip's could clash.

Comment: @TomTom HA =! fault tolerance

Comment: @pauska So you like loosing data then? Man, I hope you work... for my competitor.

Comment: @WaveyDavey Yes and no. There are mechanisms to handle high availability before that. Virtual IP load balancing. Just use the mechanisms in the client OS to give you HA on 2 concurrently running VM's.

Comment: @tomtom we are not talking about MY setup. In case you didn't notice, we are debating the right solution for the OP, which state "we could reasonably easily cope with week-old backups copies regularly from master VM to secondary VM"

Comment: Then still no need to do that. If that there windows, I would run all VM's and use NLB to distribute the load among the machines.

Comment: @TomTom, re handle HA in client: That's gonna be a pain in the ... for a rag-tag collection of various Centos's and a couple of ubuntu's

Comment: Running HA/load-balancing at the application level for every single application is just plain nonsense.

Comment: Then your best bet may be some scripting. Server 2012 can repliate the VM's (or you export/ Import, do not start) and you can then check every mnute if server 1 is up, if not start he vm's on server 2. Powershell to your rescue. Replication at least cuts down on the maintenance side when you make changes.

Comment: @TomTom, powershell - yep, looks a likely solution. Failover Cluster just looks like way too much expansion of Windows setup, for no real benefit.

Comment: @pauska - I see you and TomTom are not getting on - seriously, would you like to post an answer suggesting *your* proposal for handling the issue. I genuinely would like to hear suggestions from people

Comment: @WaveyDavey It wont be too easy though to also handle recover scenarios. Make sure to upgrade to server 2012 - has full powershell cmdlets and all the other features needed. Sadly there is no automatic restart for replications, and in larger farms that turns into a maintenance nightmare. BUt if you can couple physical machines 1:1 - that should work without getting too complex.

Comment: @WaveyDavey Check http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/05/automate-disaster-recovery-plan-with-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-replica-and-powershell-3-0.aspx#.UOv8qW8aa8E for a guidance.

Comment: @TomTom - can you expand on coupling physical servers 1:1 - do you mean some automated way, or just manage the two by hand ? If automated - is there "One Microsoft Way"(TM) to do this ?

Comment: Also, I wonder how nasty the process of migrating non AD W2000 not R2 to 2012 will be. And how long it is likely to take.

Comment: @WaveyDavey No, i mean server a has replica on server b, ONLY. If you have 10 machiens and replicate "randomly" keeping track on what to restart when is complex. If you pair them (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b) it is easy - 1a is master, 1b has copies.

Comment: No idea about time - we alawys reinstall on occasions like that. Export/Import. Convert virtual discs is adviced (from vhd to vhdx - faster and more resilient format). NO idea ahow large your servers are, but it took us a week to reinstall it all, but that was mostly because it also started a "let's get our machiens upgraded to server 2012" operation on the virtual machines themselves. The actualy Hyper-V upgarde was trivial. Remember to upgrade the integration components in the virtual machines.

Comment: @TomTom, ok, makes sense. Plan is direct 1:1 copy anyway. I *like* that article, by the way.